# NoClassDefFoundError in android map view class

Tags: android

i am using map view in my application. when i run my application logcat shows "NoClassDefFoundError". But in Manifest file i give following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

and with in application tag i put uses library also.

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/startseite" android:label="@string/app_name">
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"/>

</application>
```

Any one know what's the problem here? how to solve this error and how to display mapview

Comment: post the whole output of logcat........

Comment: are you running in device or emulator? If you are running in emulator try running in google APIs

Comment: i tried both emulator and device also, i am using google API emulator only. but i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register for a Map APi Key? You can get an example [here](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: now its working. i set flag for my intent like, Intent intent=new Intent(launchActivity.getParent(),DealerDetailsDisplay.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);